# Flour sold in grocery labeled as Yoshon. how do they do it?

Tags: yashan-chadash

According to the OU they used to store the Flour from the time it's certain that it's Yoshon & sold it during the winter. but they had Problems with worms so they started to store the Wheat. but according th them & to Rabbi Herman's Guide this is only sold in Bulk Bags of 100 LB. So my question is, how do Kemach or Dependable who sell in retail packages of 5 Lb. and claim that thier flour is Yoshon, how do they do it? storing the flour or the wheat?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Moshe. Sounds like Kemach buys the yoshon wheat as 100lbs grain bags and then grinds it up themselves, redistributing it into 5lbs flour bags? Maybe you can link to the article you saw so we can see the entire process?

Comment: http://www.kashrut.com/consumer/baked_goods/Main%20Guide-17-18-final.pdf         look on page 12

Comment: and this is the ou article about the change they made to store the wheat, not the flour.               https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/yoshon/

Comment: Don't forget that once Pesach as started all wheat harvested before then is automatically yoshon.